# Hiding Jetpack Ads from users who are signed in?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I'm just looking for some quick help if possible. I've just enabled Jetpack ads on my site, was hoping to use ad-free viewing as a Patreon reward and found the posts on [hooks](https://wordads.co/2018/02/07/how-to-control-jetpack-ad-placements-using-hooks/) and [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Is_User_Logged_in). Since the option is missing from Jetpack's own settings, I'm assuming that pasting the hooks/tags into *functions.php* is the best way to do this, but I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to coding – especially PHP – and would just like to confirm that before I go making any modifications.

I'm *guessing* that I would use something along the lines of the following *(and while I'm at it, disabling ads in the excerpt in general because they ruin my theme, haha)*:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in(true) {
add_filter( 'wordads_excerpt_disable', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'wordads_content_disable', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'wordads_inpost_disable', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'wordads_header_disable', '__return_true' );
}
```

But I'm not 100% certain. Can anyone confirm, deny, and/or edit the coding so that it's right? I'm also assuming that I can just paste it anywhere in the file, as has been the case with other database modifications I've seen?

Thanks so much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be the good one. You just have to use `is_user_logged_in()` into a hook instead of calling it directly, and probably to early.

```
function wp_se_339916() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() {
        add_filter( 'wordads_excerpt_disable', '__return_true' );
        add_filter( 'wordads_content_disable', '__return_true' );
        add_filter( 'wordads_inpost_disable', '__return_true' );
        add_filter( 'wordads_header_disable', '__return_true' );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_se_339916' );
```

Using the `template_redirect` hook could be a good solution. You'll just have to paste this into your `functions.php` file. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: thanks so much for that. I'll stick that into my code ASAP! Just wondering as well – I'm looking to disable the ad in the excerpt for *all users* as well, because I can't stand the way it's showing up on my theme. How do I do that, either within this code block or otherwise? Thanks!